# Contacts and content, many to many relationship

Tags: design-patterns, email, sharing

The below screen shot shows a prototype I am working on in which an email gets personalised for multiple people. Contacts might share part of a personalization with another contact but not the whole email.

I am managing this using name tags above sections. You can also personalize independently just by clicking on a contact name but for making a contact share a section with someone else you have to drag the name of the contact into the view section of the person you want share with.

e.g. here I was in Alice's view and I dragged Alex to Alice's first section and Ashley to Alice's second section.

However I am generally not happy with my solution due to the following:

1. Confusing to understand the grouping here (Although this will also be available in a text view mode which shows sections with headers as groups containing common edits and their members)
2. Generally I feel its a weak solution.

I really would appreciate perhaps a different angle of seeing the problem or tips etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No offense but your interface is really confusing.Until I actually read the e.g you had given, I couldnt figure out what you were trying to do here. The problem I have with your solution is that the use of tags kind of gives me an impression these two two people are tagged in each section (like how Facebook has tags). Since each section denotes to whom you are sending your content, you could take advantage of existing mail layouts to come up with a design like this:

[image]